# EGL support on linux

Tags: linux, opengl-es-2.0, nvidia, egl

I have a cross platform app, I want to compile on Linux. The problem is that the binary nVidia driver does not expose *EGL* interface (which the app uses). So to change as little of the app as possible I was wondering whether there is a wrapper which e.g. maps *GLX* to *EGL*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although *Nvidia* does not expose *EGL* / *GLES2* you can use *Mesa* and it's libs.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering whether there is a wrapper which e.g. maps GLX to EGL.

If you are using EGL to have OpenGL-ES context, one excellent wrapper is the PowerVR SDK emulator. 
It has a fair licensing model to distribute the binaries (MIT License) and can be helpful for multiplatform aplications. Just pick the libegl.so (or libegl.dll) and libglesv2.so (libglesv2.dll) from corresponding platform folder and drop with your application [see PowerVR SDK](https://community.imgtec.com/developers/powervr/graphics-sdk/)

> The SDK supports iOS, Android and Linux PowerVR devices. It also supports Windows, OS X and Linux PC emulation. Imagination's OpenGL ES emulation 
>   library, PVRVFrame, can be downloaded from our website.

On Windows platform you can also use Google's ANGLE, which translates OpenGL-ES calls to DirectX D3D (and it is amazing fast!). It also has fair license model (BSD License). There is a Microsoft branching at GitHub, with some enhancements. You can get the DLL binaries from you Google Chrome browser install folder. Look for following files: libegl.dll, libglesv2.dll and d3dcompiler_XX.dll.